# Subquery returned more than 1 value. Error when trying to remove entries based on matching colums

Tags: sql, sql-server

Good Afternoon,

I am attempting to filter the results from a query I have been running.

Originally I inserted my results into a temptable and assigned rowids then used:

```
delete from #TEMPtable
       where RowID not in ( select min(RowID) 
                         from #TEMPtable
                         group by Customer,Product)
```

This successfully removed entries so I was left with only 1 row per customer/product. (So if Steve had 5 cars and 2 Bikes the query would return 1 row for Steve, Car, other details and 1 row for Steve, bike, other details)

After this it became apparrent that for a 3 types of products I needed 1 row per customer/product/subproduct.

I attempted to use the below instead and received my error:

```
delete from #Temptable
      where RowID not in (
      (select min(RowID)  from #Temptable  where ProductID in(19,21,118) group by customer,product,subproduct),
      (select min(RowID) from #Temptable  where ProductID not in(19,21,118) group by customer,product)
      )
```

so to refer to my steve's car example we want:
1 row for Steve, Car, other details

1 row for Steve, bike, motorbike, other details

1 row forSteve, bike, Pedal Bike, other details

I'm a fairly novice SQLer so any help would be appreciated, I hope what i've posted makes sense.

Comment: added `sql-server` tag based on the `#TEMPTable` naming syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Your idea works, you need `union all` instead of a comma and change the parentheses:

```
delete from #Temptable
      where RowID not in (
      (select min(RowID)  from #Temptable  where ProductID in(19, 21, 118) group by customer, product, subproduct union all
       select min(RowID) from #Temptable  where ProductID not in(19, 21, 118) group by customer, product)
      );
```

However, there are other ways to write this logic.  Here is another way, with just one `group by`:

```
delete from #Temptable
      where RowID not in (select min(RowId)
                          from #Temptable
                          group by customer, product, 
                                   (case when ProductId in (19, 21, 188) then subproduct end)
                         );
```

This conditionally aggregates the the data, using `subproduct` only for the three products that need it.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you. I can sort understand why this works, I would need one list rather than 2 lists in my "not in".

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

**Method 1**

```
DELETE FROM #Temptable
WHERE RowID Not In 
    (
      (select min(RowID)  from #Temptable  where ProductID in(19,21,118) group by customer,product,subproduct) 
      UNION
      (select min(RowID) from #Temptable  where ProductID not in(19,21,118) group by customer,product)
    )
```

**Method 2**

```
DELETE FROM #Temptable
    WHERE RowID Not In 
        SELECT ID FROM
        (
          (select min(RowID) AS ID from #Temptable  where ProductID in(19,21,118) group by customer,product,subproduct) 
          UNION
          (select min(RowID) AS ID from #Temptable  where ProductID not in(19,21,118) group by customer,product)
        ) AS A
```